# How to create a new array selected from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am trying move data from one table to another in a mysql database using PHP.  The original table has data in a one to many relationship.  There is one column that contains the project_id (value_object_id - this is the many column), another column (value_field_id) that contains a key to define what type of data is stored in the last column (value_charvalue).  I have successfully been able to pull all the data out using the following code, but am not able to figure out how to cycle through each record to determine if it is a new project_id, contains 14,19, or 20 in the value_field_id column, and how to put the data for a new record into an array.  Each new record would need to include information from 3 records in the original table.  Thank you for any help or direction you might provide.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT value_object_id, value_field_id, value_charvalue FROM custom_fields_values ORDER BY value_object_id";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//  Add array for newly selected data????
//  $new_array = array();

/* numeric array */
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 
    // Add test to determine if value_field_id is = 14, 19 or 20
    // $new_array[project_id] = value_object_id
    // If value_field_id = 19, $new_array[name] = value_charvalue
    // If value_field_id = 14, $new_array[email] = value_charvalue
    // If value_field_id = 20, $new_array[phone] = value_charvalue

    $project_id = $row[0];
    $next_row = $row[1];    
    $third_row = $row[2];
    printf('%s, %s, %s \n', $project_id, $next_row, $third_row);
    } 

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Hm, if it comes _from_ one table, and needs to go _into_ another, isn't it simpler to write a `INSERT... SELECT...` query?

Comment: I could use an INSERT command for each record, but am challenged cycling through each row to identify if it contains the right data as many of the rows do not need to be moved.

Comment: Well, that's what `WHERE` clauses are for? Also, possibly `CASE` statements in the `SELECT` portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$projects = [];

while(...) {
  ...

  $fieldname = ...;
  $fieldvalue = ...;

  if (!isset($projects[$project_id]))
    $projects[$project_id] = [];
  $projects[$project_id][$fieldname] = $fieldvalue;
}

print_r($projects);
```

If you are on an ancient version of PHP, replace `[]` with `array()`

Answer (score 0):

So first you would need to determine if the value_field_id is either 19, 14 or 20.

```
// The field id's that you are interested in
$value_field_ids = array(19, 14, 20);

$project_id = array();

// I'm not sure why you would prefer numeric ids instead of associative?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    // Here we check if the value_field_id is 19, 14 or 20
    if(in_array($row[1], $value_field_ids)) {
        $project_id[] = array($row);
    }

    $project_id = $row[0];
    $next_row = $row[1];  
    $third_row = $row[2];   
    printf('%s, %s, %s \n', $project_id, $next_row, $third_row);
}   

// At this point you have the entire data stored in $result, as an array
// Try var_dump($result);
```

And there you have it-your newly created array.

Comment: I changed the $result to be $project_id = array(); and kept $result to reflect the original call to mysql.  Only empty returns.
$value_field_ids = array(19, 14, 20);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$projects = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    // Here we check if the value_field_id is 19, 14 or 20
    if(in_array($row[1], $value_field_ids)) {
        $projects[] = array($row);
    }

    $project_id = $projects[0];
    $next_row = $projects[1];  
    $third_row = $projects[2];   
    printf('%s, %s, %s \n', $project_id, $next_row, $third_row);
}

Comment: Right, here is the thing: 
$project_id[] = array($row); 
creates and fills a multi-dimensional array. Assuming that your query works fine, uncomment the last line I put in there and you will see the exact structure of the newly created array-as I understand, this is what you are trying to do. 
$project_id = $projects[0] 
will be incorrect as $projects[0] itself is now an array. $project_id will still need to be $row[0]. Same goes for the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

using `WHERE value_field_id IN (14, 19, 20)`

```
$query = "SELECT value_object_id, value_field_id, value_charvalue FROM custom_fields_values ORDER BY value_object_id";
```

becomes

```
$query = "SELECT value_object_id, value_field_id, value_charvalue FROM custom_fields_values WHERE value_field_id IN (14, 19, 20) ORDER BY value_object_id";
```

and manipulate whatever you want OR insert directly into other table.